# Adding Intellisense for Polymer Project DOM Components

Tags: netbeans, polymer

I am currently looking into using Google's new Polymer platform (http://www.polymer-project.org/).

I am wondering whether there is a way to add the custom elements from Polymer's project into Netbeans so that I can do autocomplete like normal HTML within Netbeans.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [my little workaround](https://github.com/ladariha/PolymerForNB). If you have HTML5 project, you can teach NetBeans your own elements/attributes. The project uses this feature for Polymer elements. It could be incomplete though, it seems like not all attributes are always mentioned in documentation

Comment: Thanks this looks good. Is there a way to make it work with a PHP project as I am going to need to have a mix of HTML5 and PHP for my project

Comment: it should work in PHP project but not in php file, only in HTML file. I filed issue https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=246642 about it. BTW I plan to update the github project to include also documentation (help) in NetBeans